# How do you use TextReplacer with python-pptx to update chart data in PPTX?

Tags: python, powerpoint, openpyxl, python-pptx

TextReplacer has been good for inserting data throughout PPTX files from excel and now I would like to edit charts using this method. I'm working with bar/pie/combo charts.

This is what I have but it's not working,

```
import re
import openpyxl
from pptx import Presentation
from python_pptx_text_replacer import TextReplacer

FL.data1=int(FL["F2"].value)
replacer = TextReplacer("TEMPLATE.pptx", slides='',
                        tables=True, charts=True, textframes=True)
replacer.replace_text( [ ('FL.data1',(FL.data1)) ] )
```

Comment: What is "*not working*"? What is the expected and what is happening instead?

Comment: @GinoMempin The 'FL.data1' isn't being replaced with the assigned value. In other slides it is replaced but not within the chart.

Comment: Something to be aware of: Charts in PowerPoint can be PPT native charts, embedded Excel charts or linked Excel charts. Or possibly even MS Graph charts. Perhaps this method only works with one or some of these chart types.